# Power BI integration with Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-logic-apps, azureportal

When power bi dataset refresh failure occurs it should trigger logic app in azure
and need to get the refresh failure details of a dataset (dataset name, dataset id and data source error) in logic app.
So far I did following,

1. I have configured "scheduled refresh" failure email notification in Power BI. Whenever refresh failure happens receiving emails with subject *"Refresh Failed: testdataset has failed to refresh"*.
   Body of the email has following details which is not useful
   *Activity ID, Request ID, Cluster Name, Refresh Start Time, Refresh End Time*
2. To interact with Power BI at API level, I have registered Azure App

How  to get refresh failure details of a dataset (dataset name, dataset id and data source error)
in Power BI to logic app? I need steps how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the email trigger for incoming emails in logic apps?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow#monitor-incoming-email

You could run an action when the subject contains "Refresh Failed:".

Or you could consider accessing the Power BI API to check the refresh history on a schedule similar to your dataset refresh.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-refresh-history

Comment: The first option which you mentioned we can trigger logic app when we receive failure notification email, as I mentioned initially that the subject contains dataset name, I need to pass datasetid to  fetch dataset details as per  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-refresh-execution-details 

The second option also requires datasetid, in the email we only get datasetname  and also I need to check refresh failures on couple of datasets in different workspaces

Comment: I couldn't find an example in my inbox, but I thought in the email there was a link to the dataset that you could parse to get the dataset id?